# Jenkins setup using Google AppEngine source code

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, cloudbees

I have created an application in google app engine and pushed my code into git provided by google. Now I want to set up Continuos Integration with cloudbees Jenkins.

When I create a job in Jenkins with repository url as url at the source code level I get following error

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h https://source.developers.google.com/p/my-application-name/r/default HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: remote error: Invalid username/password.
You may need to use your OAuth token password; Note that generated google.com passwords are not compatible with private repositories
```

The repository url I am using is:

https://source.developers.google.com/p/my-application-name/r/default

How do I create OAuth token?

Answer (score 0):

OAuth is a protocol that lets external apps request authorization to private details in a user’s GitHub account without getting their password. This is preferred over Basic Authentication because tokens can be limited to specific types of data, and can be revoked by users at any time.

All developers need to register their application before getting started. A registered OAuth application is assigned a unique Client ID and Client Secret. The Client Secret should not be shared.

Ill adive you to give the following article a read :

https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/

Also have alook at the plugin for git authentication for Jenkins:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Github+OAuth+Plugin